# Disable Chrome developer tools ⌘-[0-9] keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to disable the <kbd>⌘-[0-9]</kbd> keyboard shortcuts in Chrome's developer tools? It's frustrating to accidentally hit them when I intend to switch tabs (ex, when I hit <kbd>⌘-1</kbd> because I want to switch to the first tab, but instead being taken to the developer tools "Elements" panel).

Comment: At least in Linux, I can use Alt+<digit> to switch tabs. In OS X, that'd be Option+<digit>. Does it work?

Comment: No… It's ⌘+<digit> on the mac, and option+<digit> does nothing.

Comment: This is a known issue and should be fixed shortly.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=174606

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: This feature has [landed in Chrome 28](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=174606#c15).

1. Open the devtools.
2. Click on the Gears icon in the bottom-right corner
3. Select the General tab
4. Use the checkbox before "Enable Ctrl + 1-9 shortcut to switch panels" to toggle the preference. This option is found in the bottom-right corner of the Settings -> General tab.

---

*Previous answer, which shows how to easily change the source code of your devtools.*

There's no preference or flag to change the shortcuts, so you either have to edit the source code and build Chrome yourself, *or* change one byte in `resources.pak`.

1. First, **locate `resources.pak`**. This archive (format described [here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-dev/agGjTt4Dmcw/uekdoo_cAxkJ)) contains several static files. `resources.pak` is located in the following directory:

   - **OS X 10.7.3**: `/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/26.0.1410.65/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Resources/resources.pak`
   - **Linux** (ArchLinux): `/usr/lib/chromium/resources.pak`
   - **Windows XP**: `%AppData%\..\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\26.0.1410.65\resources.pak`
   - **Windows Vista/7/8**: `%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\26.0.1410.65\resources.pak`

   If you cannot find the file at the specified path, use your common sense. Adjust the version, Chrome/Chromium for example. Locate the Chrome executable, and find `resources.pak` close to it.
2. **Create a back-up of resources.pak in case you mess up.**
3. Open `resources.pak` (use `vim` or any other hex editor).
4. Find `_keyDown:`, and move a few lines forward (see below). Change `!` to `~`. What does this do? For all given inputs, `~value` will return a negative number, which is truthy, so the `_keyDown:` function always ends early.

I've confirmed that the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>*digit*</kbd> shortcut is disabled in Chrome/Chromium on Linux/Mac/Windows by following these steps.

### What could go wrong?

- You trashed some bytes, e.g. by using Notepad to save `resources.pak`.
- You did not edit one byte, but added/removed a byte. Remember, the resource's size is fixed!

In any of these cases, the developer tools will show up as "Not found". Chrome itself is still usable though: Sites can be browsed. If you forgot to make a backup at step 3, re-installing Chrome will fix any issues.

---

For future reference, part of the source code (source with comments at [`InspectorView.js`](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/eb4af44b6/Source/WebCore/inspector/front-end/InspectorView.js#L148-L151)):
(in the boldfaced line, replace `!` with `~`)

```
_keyDown: function(event)
{
if (!WebInspector.KeyboardShortcut.eventHasCtrlOrMeta(event))
return;


if (!event.shiftKey && !event.altKey && event.keyCode > 0x30 && event.keyCode < 0x3A) {
var panelName = this._panelOrder[event.keyCode - 0x31];
if (panelName) {
this.showPanel(panelName);
event.consume(true);
}
return;
}
```