# Extra space at beginning of console.log

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

As of a recent update, Chrome seems to be inserting spaces at the beginning of each `console.log` output. This code:

```
console.log("one");
console.log("two\nthree");
console.log("four");
```

...used to give me this expected result when running Chrome, where all the lines line up on the left edge:

[image]

Text version:

```
one
two
three
four
```

...but as of a fairly recent Chrome update (I don't know the exact version where it started, but it happens as of v39.0.2171.95), `console.log` appears to be inserting a space at the beginning of each string you ask it to output:

[image]

Text version:

```
 one
 two
three
 four
```

Note the fact that `three` isn't indented, because it's part of the same string as `two`, it's just preceded by a newline.

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/lowogu/1)

Does anyone know why that would be and how to make it stop inserting those spaces? Is it a Chrome bug? (I don't see it on [the issues list](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list), but...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first I thought it was a Linux/Windows thing, but that was just because my Linux box's copy of Chrome was out of date (v38.0.2125.111). When I updated my Linux box, the bug started showing up there, too, so presumably not a setting of some kind (I was wondering about some kind of prefix feature, for instance — but if so, it's a new one with a *really weird* default). So it's a new bug, introduced some time between then and v39.0.2171.95. I've [reported it](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=444580).

---

And in fact, they've *already* replied, identified when the regression happened, and started fixing it. Gosh.

Comment: Here's the fix: https://codereview.chromium.org/download/issue822743002_1.diff. You could wait two release cycles, or patch your devtools version using the instructions at https://stackoverflow.com/a/15937015.