# How to change text of Element Inspector tooltip/highlight via Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to change the tooltip text of of Chrome's Element Inspector. (The one you see within the page when hovering a node in the tree view). I want to add additional information there.

[image: Chrome Debugger highlight + tooltip]

Is this somehow possible? I could not find any information in the docs.

Alternatively creating a new little tooltip at another corner of the highlight rectangle (which will not interfere with the existing one) would be fine too. Thanks for any hints & tips.

Answer (score 2):

So the answer is basically "you can't do that in an extension" (as in, modify the Dev Tools tooltip).

[Charles' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30167876/934239) points to [a guide](http://smus.com/extending-chrome-developer-tools/) that talks about *replacing* the Chrome Dev Tools. It's possible using the command line of Chrome, but it's not something an extension can do.

---

You can, however, inject a content script in the page that would mimic the Dev Tool's highlighting. It will not be integrated with Dev Tools, but might be enough for your purpose.

You can take a look at [ABP's implementation](https://github.com/adblockplus/adblockpluschrome/) of element selection/highlight as a starting point. I think it's in [this file](https://github.com/adblockplus/adblockpluschrome/blob/master/include.postload.js).

Answer (score 2):

The [text format is hard-coded](https://cs.chromium.org/file:InspectorHighlight.cpp%20buildElementInfo) as the concatenation of the node name, ID and class names. Changing any of these values will change the displayed tooltip. For example, setting the class name using `element.className = 'Hello\xA0world!';` results in a tooltip containing `Hello world!` (note: I'm using the non-breaking space `\xA0` because normal spaces are replaced with dots in the title).

The previous method doesn't offer much flexibility in positioning or coloring of your custom text. A way to gain much more control over the displayed text is by editing the devtools' source code in `resources.pak`. This process is explained in detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914851/disable-chrome-developer-tools-%E2%8C%98-0-9-keyboard-shortcuts/15937015#15937015) (**read it** before continuing).

The displayed text is part of an overlay that is rendered by [InspectorOverlayPage.html](https://cs.chromium.org/file:InspectorOverlayPage.html%20%22%3Cdiv%20id=%5C%22element-title%5C%22%3E%22). Edit `resources.pak`, search for that line (e.g. by searching for `id="element-title"`) and modify it (**make sure that the number of bytes does not change**, e.g. by renaming tags, removing quotes and/or collapsing superfluous whitespace). For example:

```
OLD:  <span id="node-width"></span><span class="px">px</span><span class="px"> &#xD7; </span><span id="node-height"></span><span class="px">px</span>
NEW:  <a id=node-width></a><a class=px>px</a><a class=px> &#xD7; </a><a id=node-height></a><a class=px>px</a><a style="color:red;">My custom text</a>
```

[image]

---

### Changing colors only

If you just want to change the colors, then you can also solve the issue by changing the (hard-coded) color configuration in `resources.pak`.
The highlight colors are defined at `WebInspector.Color.PageHighlight` in [Source/devtools/front_end/common/Color.js](https://cs.chromium.org/file:Color.js%20WebInspector.Color.PageHighlight). This resource is minified and included in `resources.pak`, so if you open `resources.pak` with a hex editor and look for `WebInspector.Color.PageHighlight=`, then you will find a way to change the default color values (note: when I just tried this method, I found two occurrences of this string, I had to modify the second occurrence to get the desired effect.

For example, to change the color of the box's content, I modified the `Content` color definition. Inside `resources.pak`, there is a long line containing `WebInspector.Color.PageHighlight={Content:WebInspector.Color.fromRGBA([111,168,220,.66]),`.

After changing it to `WebInspector.Color.PageHighlight={Content:WebInspector.Color.fromRGBA([255, 0,0   ,.66]),` (**note: the number of characters must match, pad it with spaces if needed**), the default box will be red:

[image]

#### Alternatives

Instead of modifying `resources.pak`, you could also [create an extension that runs in the content of the developer tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042547/how-to-inject-javascript-into-chrome-devtools-itself) that changes the color, e.g. by calling `WebInspector.Color.PageHighlight.Content = WebInspector.Color.fromRGBA([255, 0,0,.66]);`.

Or, if you don't want to integrate with the devtools at all, you could create an extension that uses the [`chrome.debugger`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger) API and the devtools protocol to highlight a node using the [`DOM.highlightNode` command](https://cs.chromium.org/file:protocol.json%20highlightNode).

Another option is to open a feature request at https://crbug.com/new and ask for an option to change the colors. A [similar feature request was shot down](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=177983#c6), so this option won't work for your current case.

Comment: This answer is a little bit off-topic. I don't want to change the color of the highlight! I wanted to change the text (and maybe color the text). But thanks for your long answer

Comment: @Möhre Ah, my bad. I misread the question. I'll still keep it up in case someone wants to change the color rather than the text.

Comment: @Möhre I've edited the answer to include an explanation on changing the text.